# Logging out user by modifying database directly?

Tags: database, users

Is there a way to log out a user by just modifying the drupal database?

Comment: If it is the current user, you could also use the API and call session_destroy(), as user_logout() does: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.pages.inc/function/user_logout/7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete the user's session in the sessions table.

Comment: Why are there multiple sessions in the sessions for table for a user? Do I delete all of them?

Comment: The user has a sessiOn for each browser/computer where he is logged in. You only need to delete the one you want to logout.